# extjs layout scroll inside vbox

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, sencha-touch, extjs5

I have a problem with adding scrollbar to grid, that is inside of vbox container.
I can not assign height directly, because I do not know it. In that vbox container also is 'another content' with undefined height, so I can not use neither 'height', neither 'flex'. I need to make grid fill all remaining space in the page, and if there will be more rows than it could fit - i need to add scrollbar to that grid.
This is most important part of code:

```
{
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
}, 
items:[
    {
        title: 'center'
    },{
        html: 'another content'
    },{
        xtype: 'grid',
        autoScroll: true, // <-- this is not working
        columns: [
            { text: 'User', dataIndex: 'userId' }
        ],
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
            model: 'Ext.data.Record',
            fields: [
                { name: 'userId', type: 'string' }
            ],
            data: ( function(){
                var res = []
                for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
                    res.push({ userId: 'User'+i});
                }
                return res;
            })()
        })

    }
]
}
```

I tryed a lot of variants, but no success.
I also prepere some fiddles for most logical solutions(but scroll is not working there anyway):
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fmo
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fmp

Any help will be good.

Comment: maybe fine solution will be to create panel with scroll and push grid in that panel fully, but i do not know how to do this either

Comment: also instead of `vbox` coul be used `anchor`, thay bahave similar(and switching did not give any results)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove `autoScroll: true` and replace it with `flex: 1`.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fms

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {          
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: {
                        type: 'border'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    width: '100%',
                    region: 'north',
                    items: [{
                        title: 'north'
                    },{
                        html: 'another content'
                    }]
                }, 
                {
                    region: 'center',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    items: [{
                        layout: {
                            type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch'
                        }, 
                        items:[
                            {
                                title: 'center'
                            },{
                                html: 'another content'
                            },{
                                xtype: 'grid',
                                flex: 1,
                                columns: [
                                    { text: 'User', dataIndex: 'userId' }
                                ],
                                store: new Ext.data.Store({
                                    model: 'Ext.data.Record',
                                    fields: [
                                        { name: 'userId', type: 'string' }
                                    ],
                                    data: ( function(){
                                        var res = []
                                        for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
                                            res.push({ userId: 'User'+i});
                                        }
                                        return res;
                                    })()
                                })

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: good, very good, works as expected in fiddle, but not work in my project...
hence, this is an answer to this question. but I will search for diference between my fiddle and real project...
will mark as answer later.

Comment: I found the diference and solve a problem. The problem was that this my `vbox`  container is in another `vbox` container, but there where  incorrect `flex` settings. So i specify `flex: 1` for all nesting nodes, that lead to grid. Thanks a lot!